# Internet explorer (only) aborts AJAX posts intermittently

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, abort

Over a week pulling my hair out.

Using:

Jquery 1.9.1

malsup form plugin using similar to JSON example: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#json

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" /> with of without same error

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Internet explorer (8/9/10) will randomly aborts AJAX POST requests (very randomly)

By Abort, I mean, NOTHING is sent over http "at all" - it just aborts then puts tears in my eyes.

### F12 Developer tools under network reads:

URL *my url which is correct*

Result (Aborted) *it literally reads (Aborted)*

Type *blank - literally nothing in here*

Received 0B

Taken 202ms

Initiator (Pending) *it literally reads (Pending)*

### Opening capture of the Request:

Requestion header *are empty*

Requestion body *are empty*

eveything is empty

**However** under Timings tab, I notice that it says in order
Wait
Start
Start
Gap
DOMContentLoaded (event)
Load (Event)

*Should* ***start*** be there twice?? or am I somehow submitting the request twice and this is cause the abort.

I will say, successful POSTS have ***Start*** twice under the timings tab.

I also console.log errors and get:

xmlhttprequest.ReadyState 4

xmlhttprequest.Status: 12019

This When I click submit a second time it works. Customers won't like this...

```
$('#formId').ajaxForm( {
    dataType :  'json',
    cache:      false,
    beforeSend: beforeGenericPostForm,
    success :   FormResponse,
    error:      genericError
});

$('#formSubmitId').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //perform some custom simple form validation - return false if problem

    $('#formId').submit();
});
```

So **genericError** gets called and gives me error messages above.

I can console.log up until end of beforeSend: beforeGenericPostForm, function, then it dies/aborts.

This is something I have been searching for ages now and cannot find a resolve.

My form is standard HTML form and I post application/x-www-form-urlencoded and receive JSON from server with headers application/json; charset=utf-8

Does anyone have any clues or similar issues?

Or is this just a standard bug as posted below and if so, how do you get around it?

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9352

Many thanks if you have any advice, holding of from a years development on launching because of this now.

Comment: Does any form of navigation occur in the middle of your POST? If you watch in Fiddler, does the POST hit the wire at all?

Comment: No nothing at all over the wire. I'm watching in Dev tools network?

Comment: Well, for anyone interested, I tested back to pure jquery1.9.1 with standard jquery ajax posting, and still got the same errors in IE10. So to resolve this, considering the request never leaves the browser I simply repost the request up to 3 times before display a Try again message, and it seems to work like a charm, end user never knows it's happening and everything works great, it's a hack, but it's not overhead for anyone (except broken IE :)

Comment: Interestingly, and possibly even worse, I'm getting the same problem with images. Even more annoying - some of those that get the "(Aborted)" result are actually showing

Comment: This problem is driving me nuts. It clearly is IE10-internal bug (request never leaves browser) and occurs randomly. There's a windows error code for it: ERROR_WINHTTP_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm about to implement that retry-hack described by trentj. *waves fist at microsoft*

Comment: We I'm happy to report the retry-hack (some would argue retry-solution) is still working.

Comment: Maybe its a simple CORS Problem and it will cancel after OPTIONS-Call? Try using Fiddler oder any low level monitoring tool. to see what is going on over your network cable. Debug Tools from Browser (specially IE) are not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have similar issue and what I found out so far was the timing out problem in Internet Explorer, In my code I defined following handler as empty

```
xdr.onprogress = function () { };
xdr.ontimeout = function () { };
xdr.onerror = function () { };
```

and wrapped the send function in a timeout declaration

```
setTimeout(function () {
     xdr.send();
 }, 0);
```

that solved my issue. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem where IE 8  and 11 were working ok but IE 9 and 10 were not. I was also using xdomain requests for IE 10 and below as it had cross domain ajax request issues for the earlier browsers,

I found this:

http://cypressnorth.com/programming/internet-explorer-aborting-ajax-requests-fixed/

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
// Use Microsoft XDR
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "someurl");
xdr.onload = function () {
var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
{
    JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
}
processData(JSON);
};
xdr.onprogress = function(){ };
xdr.ontimeout = function(){ };
xdr.onerror = function () { };
setTimeout(function(){
    xdr.send();
}, 0);
}
```

Then do an else and do with jQuery for the up to date, decent browsers.

Answer (score -1):

you are not alone. Recently I'm hit with a similar issue in IE11. My scenario goes like, there are two ajax calls that happen from a web form, one populates data in a section of the page whereas other is a html5 video tag with src attribute pointing to the same domain. Both these requests show as pending. They seem as if both have locked up. (possibly each other?) Now, when user takes an action on the page that triggers another ajax call, like, navigation away from the page, page freezes up. To resolve the issue, introduced 'autoplay' on the video tag (this seemed to free and help complete both the earlier ajax requests) and the page behaves normally afterwards. Other browsers (chrome/firefox) work very well without this autoplay hack. This is little perplexing because there are other pages that have same set of ajax calls but only one of those pages hangs up. I could not figure out the perfect combination of those parameters for this to occur. I also think it is nothing to do with jquery because other browsers are working.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the 'type' parameter when calling an ajax.

```
$('#formId').ajaxForm( {
    type :  'POST',
    dataType :  'json',
    cache:      false,
    beforeSend: beforeGenericPostForm,
    success :   FormResponse,
    error:      genericError
});
```

Answer (score -4):

try removing KB2962872. It solved my problem in peoplesoft90/tools8.52
kind regards

Comment: Yeah, besides that, it could only help a single computer to view the page.You can't remove security fixes on every computer that views the website.